# Cannot make TextArea editable even after removing readonly : Html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

JavaScript:

```
var editBtn = document.getElementById('editBtn');
var saveBtn = document.getElementById('saveBtn');
var textAreaHtml = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea");

editBtn.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    textAreaHtml[0].removeAttribute('readonly');
    textAreaHtml[0].readOnly = 'false';
});

saveBtn.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    textAreaHtml[0].removeAttribute('readonly');
    textAreaHtml[0].readOnly = 'true';
});
```

Html:

```
<div class="panel-body">
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="apexClass" id="autocomplete" placeholder="Type the name of the Apex class you want to edit"/>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group-vertical" style="padding: 1%">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="editBtn">Edit</button>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-content" align="left">

            <div id='error' style='display:none'>{{apexClassWrapperError.message}}</div>

            <div>{{apexClassWrapper.name}}</div>
            <pre class="prettyprint">
                <code class="language-java">
                    <textarea ng-model="apexClassWrapper.body" id="apexBody" readonly="true">{{apexClassWrapper.body}}</textarea>
                </code>
            </pre>
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="saveBtn" ng-click="postdata(apexClassWrapper)">Save</button>
    </div>
```

I have two buttons, save and edit. I have placed event listener for Edit and save to make text area as editable, but this is not working. I am not able to edit the TextArea in the UI? Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some slight tweaking to your click event handlers, you should be in business.

```
editBtn.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    textAreaHtml[0].removeAttribute('readonly');    
});

saveBtn.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    textAreaHtml[0].setAttribute('readonly', true);
});
```

Your edit button was setting readOnly to false, but readonly is a boolean attribute.  When it is present it makes the textarea readonly regardless of if it has a true or false value.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `readonly`, use the HTML attribute `contenteditable`!

I have never used `readonly` but by toggling the boolean on `contenteditable` you should be cookin!

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_contenteditable.asp

Comment: Using contenteditable, does not make make the text area readonly when the page loads. The text area is still editable if we use 'contenteditable'

`<textarea ng-model="apexClassWrapper.body" id="apexBody" contenteditable="false">{{apexClassWrapper.body}}</textarea>`